# Can't get Data via Graphql from Couchdb Server

Tags: express, couchdb, graphql, graphql-js

I am using Couchdb server running in a Docker Build on my Mac. 
To access the Data I run an express app via node. 
After Building my Schema for the Graphql and test it with the Graphql Interface, I am able to get the Data from a specific User but not the Document for all the Users from my users resolver.

Here is my Code:

//resolvers

```
var resolvers = {
    users: () => {
        var statement = "SELECT META(user).id, user.* FROM `" + bucket._name + "` AS user WHERE user.type = 'user'";
        var query = Couchbase.N1qlQuery.fromString(statement);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            bucket.query(query, (error, result) => {
                if(error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
      },
    user: (data) => {
        var id = data.id;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          bucket.get(id, (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              return reject(error);
            }
            resolve(result.value);
          });
        });
      }
};
```

//express setup

```
app.use("/graphql", ExpressGraphQL({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: resolvers,
  graphiql: true
}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("lisntening...")
});
```

//Schema

```
var schema = BuildSchema(`
  type Query{
    user(id: String!): User,
    users: [User]
  }
  type User{
    id: String,
    profileImage: String,
    birthdate: String,
    reviews: [String],
    premium: Boolean
  }
`);
```

When I try my query like this:

```
{
  users{
    id
  }
}
```

i get the following error msg returned:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "syntax error - at user",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 31,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "users"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "users": null
  }
}
```

The specific user query from the second resolver works fine!

Here my test document in the Database:

```
{
  "id": "ohuibjnklmönaio",
  "profileImage": "pic",
  "birthdate": "date",
  "reviews": [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "premium": true,
  "type": "user"
}
```